# Risks of keeping file open forever

Tags: python, memory, io

I am writing an application that requires reading the next line from a 1GB file exact every 5 minutes; when the end is reached it should start from the top

I had 2 solutions in mind but I'm unsure which one is the best

**Solution 1**

```
class I:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def lineFromFile(self) -> str:
        with open('file.txt') as file:
            for i in range(self.count):
                file.readline()
            line = file.readline()
            if not line:
                file.seek(0)
                self.count = 0
            line = file.readline()
            self.count += 1
        return line
```

**Solution 2**

```
class I:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open('file.txt')

    def lineFromFile(self) -> str:
        line = self.file.readline()
        if not line:
            self.file.seek(0)
            line = self.file.readline()
        return line
```

Comment: Why not close and reopen the file every 5 minutes and keep track of the last line read instead of tying up resources?

Comment: That's solution 1 but closing/reopening the file and scrolling alllll the way down to a specific line seems not the best solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Solution 1, but don't read line-by-line every time you open the file. Save the last offset read, and `seek` there directly. Also, you only want to call `file.readline()` a second time if the first call returned the empty string.

```
class I:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.offset = 0

    def lineFromFile(self) -> str:
        with open('file.txt') as file:
            file.seek(self.offset)
            line = file.readline()
            if not line:
                file.seek(0)
                self.count = 0
            else:
                line = file.readline()
            self.count += 1
            self.offset = file.tell()
        return line
```

Comment: Might as well remove the count variable as offset replaces the use of it.

Comment: I'm staying agnostic as to whether `self.count` is used elsewhere by the class.

Comment: I'm assuming that since solution 2 doesn't have a count variable.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the biggest risk of *lazily* reading from a file is another process writing to the file while you're reading from it.

Do the contents of the file change?  Is the file massive?  If not, just read the whole file at startup.

Does the file change a lot? Are lots of other processes writing to it? Can other processes delete lines?  If that's the case, you should probably just store your `seek`/line number position and then reopen and close the file every 5 minutes, check if you're at the end of file and keep reading. In this case you should also use some type of *lock file* or other synchronization mechanism to prevent multiple processes from trying to read and write from the same file at the same time.

Comment: If you're trying to get to a specific location in the file, then yes, `seek` will be faster, since you don't actually have to read any of that data.  If you actually want every line and you're going to read it anyway, just use `readline`